# Understanding line in Ramsey's Theorem proof

Tags: graphs, proof-techniques

The following is from [lecture notes](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ewgunther/127m12/notes/day26.pdf) for Concepts in Mathematics from CMU (William Gunther):

I am confused about the bolded sentence in the last line quoted here:

**Theorem 4 (Ramsey's Theorem).** *For any k, l, there is some N such that for any edge two coloring of $K_N$ with colors 0 and 1 there is either a monochromatic k-clique of color 1 or a monochromatic l clique of color 2.*

*Proof:* We prove this by induction on $n+m$.

If $k=1$ then we are done as any graph with contain a monochromatic 1-clique, so the $N$ we find is $N=1$.

Similiarly is $l=1.$

Therefore, suppose that we are at $k,l$ are not 1 and assume it's true for all pairs of smaller sum. We want to prove that it is true for $k$ and $l$.

Our central claim is that we can guarantee a monochromatic k-clique of color 1 or a monochromatic l-clique of color 2 for a graph of order $R(k-1,l)+R(k,l-1)$ vertices. Pick a vertex; which ever your favorite is. Call it $v.$ Now, look at all the edges that that vertex is connected to. There is a lot of them; namely $R(k-1,1)+R(k,l-1)-1$ many.

Each of these is either colored 0 or 1. Let $V_0$ be all the vertices that $v$ connected to that vertex are colored 0, and $V_1$ the ones that it is colored red.

Okay, the graph has $R(k-1,l)+R(k,l-1)$ vertices, and some are in $V_0$ and some are in $V_1$, and then there is $v$ which is in neither. **A moment's thought shows that there are either $R(k-1,l)$ vertices in $V_0$ or $R(l,k-1)$ in $V_1$ (why? well, if not then there cannot be that many vertices in the graph!).**

My confusion:

1. How did we know that we could break up the sum $R(k−1,1)+R(k,l−1)$ to either $V_0$ or $V_1$? For instance, where previously in the proof have we shown that it cannot be the case that $V_0$ = $R(k−1,1)/2$ and $V_1$ = $R(k−1,1)/2 +R(k,l−1)$?
2. Generally, it looks to me like although our inductive hypothesis holds true for $R(k-1,1)$ and $R(k,l-1)$ separately, how do we know that in a graph that is a union of the two, it still holds for the two components? (ie. does combining them as a sum interfere with the properties of each separately)?
3. Doesn't the author mean "$R(k−1,l)$ vertices in $V_0$ or $R(k,l-1)$ vertices in $V_0$" (rather than $V_1$ in the last clause)?